# Fill an ObservableCollection faster

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I assume these two code snippets do the same. I would like to know which one is faster and why? One of them is much faster than the other?

```
ObservableCollection<Something> CollectionToFill;
ObservableCollection<Something> SourceCollection;
```

First one:

```
CollectionToFill = new ObservableCollection<Something>(SourceCollection.Where(item => item.Name.Equals("ABC")).Select(item => item));
```

Second one:

```
foreach (var item in SourceCollection)
{
    if (item.Name.Equals("ABC"))
    {
        CollectionToFill.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware, that **these 2 do different things**. The first one creates a new collection and replaces reference from the old one. The second one adds items to existing collection. It may sound as the same, but it's not. But anyway.

The first one will be faster, because it won't raise events after each element.

`Add` uses `InsertItem` internally, which looks like that:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
{
    this.CheckReentrancy();
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);
}
```

`base.InsertItem` is declared as:

```
protected virtual void InsertItem(int index, T item)
{
    this.items.Insert(index, item);
}
```

As you can see, there are 3 events raised when item is added.

Constructor adds the items directly into underlying collection, without raising any events, using `CopyFrom` method:

```
public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }
    this.CopyFrom(collection);
}

private void CopyFrom(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    IList<T> items = base.Items;
    if (collection != null && items != null)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                items.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```